# Show modal on link click

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I have this link and I want to show the modal below with id "modal" when this link with id "showItem" is clicked but Im not understanding how to achive that.

Do you know what is necessary to achieve that?

HTML Link:

```
<a href="#" id="showItem" class="block relative" >
  <img alt="profil" src="images/img/1.jpg"
       class="mx-auto object-cover rounded-full h-40 w-40 "/>
</a>
```

HTML Modal:

```
<div id="modal"  class="inline-block align-bottom bg-white rounded-lg text-left overflow-hidden shadow-xl transform transition-all sm:my-8 sm:align-middle sm:max-w-lg sm:w-full">
  <div class="bg-white px-4 pt-5 pb-4 sm:p-6 sm:pb-4">
    <div class="sm:flex sm:items-start">

      <div class="mx-auto flex-shrink-0 flex items-center justify-center h-12 w-12 rounded-full bg-red-100 sm:mx-0 sm:h-10 sm:w-10">

      </div>
      <section>
        <div class="py-20 bg-gray-50 radius-for-skewed">
          <div class="container mx-auto px-4">
            <div class="flex flex-wrap items-center -mx-3">
              <div class="w-full lg:w-1/3 px-3 mb-8 lg:mb-0">
                <ul class="flex flex-wrap flex-row lg:flex-col justify-center lg:justify-start space-x-6 lg:space-x-0">
                  <li>
                    <button class="text-2xl lg:text-4xl mb-4 text-gray-300 hover:text-gray-400 font-bold">Item 1
                    </button>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <button class="text-2xl lg:text-4xl mb-4 text-gray-300 hover:text-gray-400 font-bold">Item 2
                    </button>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <button class="text-2xl lg:text-4xl mb-4 text-gray-900 font-bold">Item 1</button>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <button class="text-2xl lg:text-4xl mb-4 text-gray-300 hover:text-gray-400 font-bold">Item 5
                    </button>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
              <div class="w-full lg:w-2/3 px-3">
                <div class="flex p-6 flex-wrap bg-white rounded-lg shadow">
                  <div class="w-full lg:w-1/2 lg:pl-3 lg:mt-6 order-first lg:order-last">
                    <h4 class="text-2xl font-bold font-heading">Item 1</h4>
                    <p class="mb-6 text-gray-500">Desc</p>
                    <p class="mb-6 text-gray-500 leading-loose">Desc3</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `onclick` attribute to the link and call a JavaScript function to show the modal and return false to prevent browser calling the url.

```
<a href="#" id="showItem" class="block relative" onclick="showModal(); return false;">
```

Now hide your modal in CSS using `display` property.

```
#modal {
    display: none;
    /* your custom styles */
}
```

Add another style with active class. So the modal will only popup when it's active.

```
#modal.active {
    display: block;
}
```

Now in JavaScript add the active class to modal when the link is clicked.

```
const showItemBtn = document.getElementById('showItem');
const modal = document.getElementById('modal');

function showModal() {
    modal.classList.add('active');
}
```

That's all.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know how to increase the width of the modal?

Comment: I see you're using tailwind framework. Just change `max-w-` class on modal to the width you want. Example `max-w-xl`. Just can find more here https://tailwindcss.com/docs/max-width

Comment: Thanks! It should be in the outter div, in this "<div id="modal"  class="inline-block align-bottom bg-white rounded-lg text-left overflow-hidden shadow-xl transform transition-all sm:my-8 sm:align-middle sm:max-w-lg sm:w-full">? Its not working propely using the class here.

Comment: Just change `sm:max-w-lg` to `sm:max-w-xl`